# When logo is wrapped in an <a> tag in Bootstrap, navbar-toggler aligns left and under the logo image

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I am new to coding and I appreciate this will be a very basic question. I am putting a very basic navbar together using Bootstrap 4. As per the documentation, I have been putting the logo image within an `<a>` tag and giving this tag the class of `navbar-brand`. My understanding is that when there is a logo item, it aligns left and the menu items i.e. links, align right by default.

In my case, I am using only a logo image and it all aligns correctly until I resize the screen to a smaller size and it changes to the navbar-toggler (which is what I want). When I do this though, the menu icon appears on the left, underneath the logo. I would like the toggler to appear on the right, as it appears in the bootstrap documentation. I have checked and there doesn't appear to be any padding or similar pushing it underneath it.

This is the code I have been using (the menu items are just placeholder for now while I get the functionality working)

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img class="logo-img" src="media/HBS - Large Logo - Pink - Transparent Background.png" alt="" />
  </a>

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon mr-auto"></span>
          </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a
                >
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a
                >
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
```

I read a few other entries on here and someone had got around this by removing the `<a>` tag and applying the `navbar-brand` class to the image itself. When I do this, it works and the navbar-toggler aligns right as it should, only now the menu items when in large screen mode `align-left` alongside the logo.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <img class="logo-img navbar-brand" src="media/HBS - Large Logo - Pink - Transparent Background.png" alt="" />
```

It was always my understanding that the navbar-brand class and logo image should be held within an `<a>` tag? When there is no image and it's the only text for the navbar logo, all the alignment works fine, it's only when there is an image.

Sorry for what is a very basic question - I'm learning to code at the moment so I am keen that I am getting the fundamentals right rather than hacking around things. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When I try your html with a placeholder image, it seems to work as expected? The nav toggler is on the right. It only goes below the image if the viewport becomes too small to fit both the image and the togger, in which case the toggler wraps below the image.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me and that makes complete sense. The only other thing is I can think of is that the original image itself is quite large but I'm then using css to reduce the size, so down to 30% of it's normal size. I've only now noticed that the navbar-brand is taking up the full width of the bar when I inspect it - could this be the culprit?